# CUPS doesn't change default path

Tags: printing, pdf

My problem with CUPS is the following: I try to change the default path of the output of CUPS PDF files and it doesn't work. I edit the /etc/cups-pdf.conf file and add my path and it still doesn't work, both with relative and absolute paths.
I've tried it with different versions of Ubuntu, both with Ubuntu 16, Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 19.